# Identify folders with a specific string in Python

Tags: python, string, directory

Simple question here -- all I want to do is identify the folders in a directory which share a specific stub.  For example, I would want to isolate all folders which begin with "B07", and they would include "B07.1", "B07.2", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `os.listdir` or `os.walk` and filter directories, or `glob.glob`...

```
import os
folders = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x.startswith('B07')]
```

Comment: +1. You could use regular expressions instead of `x.startswith` for support wildcards: `re.match('^B07.*$', x)`

Comment: The glob module is a better choice

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path = './'
list = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if i.startswith('B07') and os.path.isdir(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
glob.glob('*foo*')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html

Comment: Glob's brilliant for picking up whole directory trees.